# How do I read this panel?

Tags: one-piece, manga-production, panel-arrangement

[image: Nami talking to Luffy inside. There are 2 text bubbles on the right and 1 on the left.]

I have just started reading one piece and came across this panel. I think I know the order panels should be read and I know to go from top right to bottom left within the panels, but I found the one above a little confusing. What order should I read the bubbles and who is talking in each box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right order to read these is as you stated:

1. Top right,
2. Bottom right,
3. Left.

I believe Nami is the one doing all the talking, but I get why you'd be confused: the speech bubble on the left has a really short tail, and Luffy is closer to it than Nami is. However, judging by context (the bottom right and left statements *seem* to follow logically) plus the fact that Luffy doesn't have his mouth open, I would say it's fairly reasonable to assume that Nami is doing all the talking.